# Can I use One object at 3 or more class?

Tags: java, android, class, object

At- android programming,

I have a problem that, I need to use One object at 3~ more class.

First, I make my object about character class, at class A.

Here's Example.

- class character.java

  ```
  Character(int food, int water, String ch_name, int health_num) {
      health = health_num;
      name = ch_name;
      use_food = food;
      use_water = water;
  }
  ```
- class A.java

  ```
  Character ch1 = new Character(10,10,"hi,10);
  ```
- class B.java

how can I use that "ch1" object at class B??

Help me please..

Comment: And there's one more problem :( Class B.java is a Fragment and Class A is an android Activity.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do that, simple thing is that you can create a method `myChar()` in `class A` which returns the `Character` object as shown below:

```
public class A {

  public Character myChar() {
  Character ch1 = new Character(10,10,"hi",10);// " not closed in your code, ensure
    return ch1;//return ch1
  }
}


public class B {

  public Character myBMethod() {
     A a = new A();
     Character ch1 = a.myChar();//call myChar() method and collect ch1 
  }
}
```

---

Also, as a side note, always keep the constructor argument names same as the instance variables and use `this` operator as shown below so that the code will be clear:

```
public Character(int health, int name, String use_food, int use_water){
        this.health = health_num;//use this operator
        this.name = ch_name;
        this.use_food = food;
        this.use_water = water;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You could pass the object through an intent although you may need to make the object parcelable.

2.You could also create a database online like firebase where you could referece from any class

3.Or if you dont want to go learning about parcelable you could just pass the attributes of the objects through an intent like

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ToClass.class);
i.putExtra("healthNum", object.getHealthNum);
//do this for all the fields
startActivity(i);
```

Hope this helps